# Combine 2 logical raid 0 drives to 1 logical raid 1 drive

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array, fault-tolerance

I have an HP Proliant server with an P410i embedded array controller.

The server was originally setup with 6 physical drives with the OS on 1 logical drive with a raid 0 and 5 physical drives setup as a raid 5. Not the way I would have done it but is what it is. Well, we got an expected drive failure on the OS drive. The network admin at the time could not add a drive to the hardware array so he mirrored the drive in disk management using software mirror. Lo and behold the OS drive has finally failed.

I found out the hard way that a software mirror does not mirror the boot sector. So I was able to make a bootable disk and get the server back up and running on the mirrored drive that is still good. So now I am at the point of getting fault tolerance setup back up and would rather do a hardware array.

So in my Array Management right now I show 3 logical drives. 2 Logical drives are showing as seperate arrays of 1 physical drive running raid 0. I am trying to find a way if possible to convert these two Raid 0 drives into one logical Raid 1 drive without losing any data since this the operating system drive.

If I can get these two Raid 0 drives into 1 logical Raid 1 drive I believe I can recreate the MBR then and make them bootable as well.

Any help or suggestion on how to combine the arrays woulbe appreciated.

Windows 2008 R2 Std

Array config

logicaldrive 1 (136.7 GB, RAID 0, OK)

```
physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
```

array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

```
logicaldrive 2 (546.8 GB, RAID 5, OK)

physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
```

array C (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

```
logicaldrive 3 (136.7 GB, RAID 0, OK)

physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
```

SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250 (WWID: 5001438022EBB6EF)

Comment: What operating system is this? Can you please show the output of the hpacucli (or hpssacli) utility using the `ctrl all show config` and `ctrl all show config detail` commands.

Comment: The OS is windows 2008 R2 Std Edition. Here is the current array config:                                                              Array A
logicaldrive 1 (136.7 GB, RAID 0, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 146 GB, OK)

Comment: array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)
logicaldrive 2 (546.8 GB, RAID 5, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
array C (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)
logicaldrive 3 (136.7 GB, RAID 0, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250 (WWID: 5001438022EBB6EF)

Comment: Please post it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *add* a disk to an existing array.

In this case, you probably want to delete whatever is on **Array C**. Add that drive to **Array A**.

If you do so, the fault-tolerance level of **logicaldrive 1** should become RAID 1.

The GUI utility will be easiest for you... but the CLI process will be something like:

```
controller slot=0 array C delete forced
```

> The add command adds a physical drive or spare to the specified
>   array or    logical drive. Adding physical drives is the same as
>   expanding an array.

```
controller slot=0 array A add drives=1I:1:1
```

> modify [raid=0|1|1adm|1+0|1+0adm|5|50|6|60|?]
>                   [stripsize=8|16|32|64|128|256|512|1024|default|?]    Migrates the specified logical drive to the desired raid level and/or
>   strip    size. The implied units of stripsize are KB. The target can
>   be any valid    logical drive.

```
controller slot=0 logicaldrive 1 modify raid=1 stripsize=default
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the options in the GUI. I will try going through the CLI today and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: In the GUI, it should be very clear... You need to click on the Array or Logical drive for the options to appear.

Comment: In the GUI the only options I am getting are delete array or more information. I went ahead and went with CLI and everything seems to be working now. Thanks